# Using an async iterable to chain promises

Tags: javascript

I have an array of items (`projects`) I want to upload, one by one in sequence.

I know how to do this by constructing a promise chain, but I wanted to try and use an `async` iterator and `for...await`.

First I map the projects to arrow functions which will, when called, invoke the upload; then I create an `async` iterable via an `async` generator function.

Then I use `for...await` to loop over the `async` iterable.

Is this an idiomatic approach?

For example, `(p)=>()=>upload(p)` looks strange to me, as does the IIFE `(async function*() { for (let p of arr) yield p() }())`.

```js
const upload = ({name}) => 
    new Promise((resolve) => 
        setTimeout(() => resolve(`Response for upload of: ${name}`), 1000))

const asyncIter = (arr) => (async function*() { for (let i of arr) yield i() }())

const uploadInSeries = async (arr) => {
    const iter = asyncIter(arr.map((i) => () => upload(i)))
    for await(let response of iter) {
        console.log(response)
    }
}

const projects = [{ name: "P1" }, { name: "P2" }, { name: "P3" }]
uploadInSeries(projects)
```

Comment: No, this is not idiomatic. You don't need to use `for await … of` for an asynchronous, sequential loop - a normal `for … of` loop with an `await` in the body will do just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a usecase for an async iterable. Async iterables only make sense if you don't know wether you have a next element or not. In your case however, the number of requests is already known, so you can just do

```
 for(const el of arr)
   await request(el);
```